# Name array in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been searching around for a solution for quite some time, hoping someone could point me to an answer or alternative solution...

I am looking to implement a input name array using the Rails form helpers.

So traditionally in html, I would just write something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email[]" value="blah" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" value="blah2" />
```

Does anyone know how an array like this can be achieved using rails helpers?    { Doesnt work }

```
<%= f.text_field :email[] %>
<%= f.text_field :email[] %>
```

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the form tag helpers to create the inputs you want.

```
= text_field_tag 'email[]', 'blah'
= text_field_tag 'email[]', 'blah2'
```

See here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html for more info.

To use `text_field` instead of the tag version your modem would need to respond to the `email[]` method.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually looking for the text_field solution.  Do you have a reference, or an example i can roll with?

Comment: What are you trying to save exactly? Is this an associated model? Or do you want to just pass an array to a method on the model? Either way you're going to need to use `fields_for` to accept an array of values. Doco is here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: Very high level: I am allowing a user to choose how many users he would like to email. Based on the number he/she chooses I dynamically generate x number of table rows.  These values, first_name last_name and email are associated with a non-database model.  I would like to use this model to perform various validations on the array.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! I just used text_field_tag and used something like applicant[num][first_name] which gave me exactly what i wanted.